# I need to send encrypted value in API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sending encrypted value in API like this

```
id=${JSON.stringify(result)}
```

value is going in API but what happening here is that, in console the  value is coming right

```
jppCfwK2LjEKtRXokf9nO+z6ieojEuJ9:TuiAg1Odt5JASNyXAryuv4Q/iGkRh4ts
```

but when I send this value to API with `+` inside of the value, it's being sent as a blank space. The value  going to API

```
jppCfwK2LjEKtRXokf9nO z6ieojEuJ9:TuiAg1Odt5JASNyXAryuv4Q/iGkRh4ts
```

The code:

```
const secretKey = Buffer.from('USED_VALIDATION_', 'utf8')
// Make sure your data is also a Buffer of Uint8Array

const skey= Buffer.from(review_id, 'utf8')
const encrypted = nacl.secretbox(skey, nonce, secretKey)
// We can now store our encrypted result and our nonce somewhere

const result = `${encodeBase64(nonce)}:${encodeBase64(encrypted)}`
console.log("uuuuuuuuuu", result)

Axios.get(`${DJANGO_SERVER_ADDRESS}/get/completed/?id=${JSON.stringify(result)}&screen=first`, config)
          .then(response => this.setState({ sum: response.data[0] }))
```

Comment: URL encode and decode

Comment: URL encode and decode mean can you explain some more

Comment: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)